# Как стилизовать отдельное слово в тексте лишь в css файле без добавления лишних тегов

Tags: html, css, css3, css-selectors

У меня есть текст помещённый в параграф:

```html
<p class="header">Welcome to wonderful place</p>
```

Я хочу выделить слово **wonderful** другим фоном.
Как я могу это сделать в CSS-файле, без добавления лишних тегов (таких, как `<span>` и т.п.)?

Comment: Никак, только обернуть нужное слово каким-то тегом и уже после этого стилизовать его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы выделить (стилизовать, применить индивидуальный стиль) отдельное слово в параграфе, его необходимо "*вручную*" обернуть отдельным тегом, например `span`, и соответственно в CSS написать нужный стиль. Пример такой реализации:

```css
.header>span {font-weight:bold; background:pink;}
```

```html
<p class="header">Welcome to <span>wonderful</span> place</p>
```

Можно поступить другим образом - применить JavaScript. Пример такой реализации:

```js
(function() {
  var header = document.querySelector('.header');
  var word = 'wonderful',
    regexp = new RegExp(word, 'i');
  if (regexp.exec(header.innerHTML)) {
    var reg = new RegExp(word, 'g');
    header.innerHTML = header.innerHTML.replace(reg, '<span style="font-weight: bold; background:pink;">' + word + '</span>');
  }
}());
```

```html
<p class="header">Welcome to wonderful place</p>
```

С помощью скрипта найти нужное слово и применить к нему стиль. Но и здесь найденное слово будет обернуто отдельным тегом. За вас это сделает скрипт. Это не обязательно может быть тег `span`. Любой тег, который вы укажете. Но он должен быть, это крайняя необходимость для того, чтобы для отдельного слова применить индивидуальный стиль.

Других вариантов, увы, нет.